# getting number in an icon

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a count of comments and I need some help getting the numbers inside the comment icon. If I try to get it in the comment it will not display the way it should display.

The code for the comments on the right side:

```
echo '<span style="float:right; margin-top:15px; margin-left:5px;">reacties</span> 
    <span style="float:right; color:grey; margin-top:15px"class="fa fa-comment">' 
    . implode($app->count_reactie($topic['id'])) .'</span>';
```

It should put the number inside of the icon, but it's showing next to it instead.

Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: *"How it look like now."* - and the way it *should* look like?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  IMAGES of code are not acceptable.

Comment: You should try googling before posting... this might be a helpful resource: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/463/how-to-use-numbers-on-icons-with-fontawesome

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It should put the number inside of the icon.

Comment: @WilliamHampshire I tried this http://blog.fontawesome.io/2014/05/19/stacking-text-and-icons/ but I cant get it to work it will make the icon bigger and not paste the number aligned in the comment icon

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using stacking of icon and text.

```css
.fa-stack-2x {
  color: black;
}

.fa-stack-1x {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack">
    <span class="fa fa-comment fa-stack-2x"></span>
    <strong class="fa-stack-1x">
        2    
    </strong>
</span>
```

You may need to fix the positioning and size using additional CSS, also look for any inherited CSS.
As suggested in comments, read [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/463/how-to-use-numbers-on-icons-with-fontawesome) article to understand the stacking of fa icons.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{font-size:14px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <span class="fa-stack">
    <span class="fa fa-comment fa-stack-2x"></span>
    <strong class="fa-stack-1x" style="color:#fff;"> 1 </strong>
</span>
```